# cooltooltips with Preview on Mac

Tags: comments, preview, acrobat

When I try to use the 'cooltooltips' package for adding notes to my PDFs and I try to view them with Preview (10.1) on Mac it does not work. When I hover over 'This text' nothing happens. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this?

[image: **enter image description here**]

This is how it should look like and how Acrobat Reader displays it. Acrobat Reader is working fine but I don't like it to much.

[image: This is how it should look like and how Acrobat Reader displays it]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Make a feature request for preview?

Comment: There are many Acrobat specific properties that most other PDF viewers don't support, I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that the is no option right now to make it work unless to make a feature request